# Python list slicing exercise doesn't make sense

Tags: python, slice

I understand that the [start:end] notation means the first number is the position in the list where the slicing start and the last number is the position -1 in the list where the slicing ends, but in this example

```
 U= [2, 'haha', [5,6,9], 3, 2, 1] ; 
 U[1:2]=[] ; 
 U[2:]=[] ;
```

The resulting slice is:

```
 U= [2, [5,6,9]]
```

Why is this the answer? I get that in the second step 3,2,1 gets eliminated. But why is the resulting slice [2,[5,6,9]] and not [5,6,9]

Comment: Print the intermediate result rather than imagining you know what it is

Comment: print the list after the first step. and then try to understand what happened. repeat the same after 2nd step. EDIT: Haha, cheers lads, looks like we're all on the same page.

Comment: Hi Shay, and welcome to StackOverflow! Try printing the intermediate state of the list to make sure you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python list slices can be replaced by iterables.

You start with this:

```
U = [2, 'haha', [5,6,9], 3, 2, 1] ;
```

`U[1:2]` is `'haha'` (From element `1` up-to-but-not-including `2`), so replacing that with an empty iterable `[]` essentially removes `'haha'` from the list.

At that point, you have `[2, [5,6,9], 3, 2, 1]`.

`U[2:]` is from element index `2` to the end, which is `[3, 2, 1]`. Again, as before, setting this to the empty iterable `[]`, deletes these three elements, leaving `[2, [5,6,9]]`

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining

Answer (score 1):

Using the python console may make the example easier to understand:

```
>>> U = [2, 'haha', [5, 6, 9], 3, 2, 1]
>>> U
[2, 'haha', [5, 6, 9], 3, 2, 1]
```

Get rid of second element.

```
>>> U[1:2]=[]
>>> U
[2, [5, 6, 9], 3, 2, 1]
```

Get rid of everything past the second element.

```
>>> U[2:] = [];
>>> U
[2, [5, 6, 9]]
```